# What is the least-bad way to create Python classes at runtime?

Tags: python, class

I am working with an ORM that accepts classes as input and I need to be able to feed it some dynamically generated classes. Currently, I am doing something like this contrived example:

```
def make_cls(_param):
   def Cls(object):
       param = _param
   return Cls

A, B = map(make_cls, ['A', 'B'])

print A().foo
print B().foo
```

While this works fine, it feels off by a bit: for example, both classes print as `<class '__main__.Cls'>` on the repl. While the name issue is not a big deal (I think I could work around it by setting `__name__`), I wonder if there are other things I am not aware of.
So my question is: **is there a better way to create classes dynamically or is my example mostly fine already?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4513192/python-dynamic-class-names

Comment: As Roman notes below, you will want to use `type` to dynamically create classes. The top answer in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/100003/what-is-a-metaclass-in-python) covers this in very good detail.

Comment: "An ORM"?  Which ORM?  Odds are good the ORM does much of this for you.

Comment: @S.Lott: I'm playing with sqlalchemy. Anyway, I think the origin of the issue is not in the ORM but actually in me deciding it would be overall simpler to use a bunch of tables with similar schemas instead of bundling them in a single table.

Comment: Why would you need to create a "dynamically generated class"?  Does your database design have tables which are created dynamically?

Comment: Oh, its not really that "dynamic" - it runs when I'm loading the DB and I happen to have some tables that share the same schema.

Comment: Multiple tables in one schema is not a problem.  I don't get why creating "dynamically generated class" is even relevant.

Comment: @S.Lott: That is probably just me abusing the ORM a bit :) I want to create a separate entity and relationships for each of those tables.

Comment: That's the way it works out of the box.  I don't get why the ordinary SQLAlchemy is not working for you.

Comment: Are you looking for this?  http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/sqlsoup.html

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What is class? It is just an instance of `type`.  For example:

```
>>> A = type('A', (object,), {'s': 'i am a member', 'double_s': lambda self: self.s * 2})
>>> a = A()
>>> a
<__main__.A object at 0x01229F50>
>>> a.s
'i am a member'
>>> a.double_s()
'i am a memberi am a member'
```

From the [doc](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#type):

> type(name, bases, dict)
>
> Return a new type object. This is essentially a dynamic form of the class statement.

Comment: Since type is only receiving these 3 parameters, am I safe to assume that the name was really the only thing that was going wrong or are there other advantages to using `type` too?

Comment: A nice way to package this is to wrap it in a function that takes keyword arguments, so you can easily specify the attributes of the new class in the function call.

Comment: @missingno Well, you approach would be useful while creating some complex classes (for example, addition of `classmethod` with usage of `type` would be ugly), but if you need to build some complex in runtime, then probably something really bad happened to your architecture :) `type` is just recommended solution for such things.