# Count number of classes and class hierarchies in a Python package

Tags: python, class-hierarchy

I have a directory with many subdirectories with Python source code which correspond to a Python package. I want to count how many classes and root classes (top of hierarchies) are contained in these directories/package.
Any easy way to do this?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1796180/python-get-list-of-all-classes-within-current-module

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to write a Python script for that. From the command line type:

```
grep -c "^class " *.py
```

and will return the number of classes in the current directory for each .py file. To find if a class is a top class I'm afraid you will have to import each and query each module.

Comment: can this be done recursivelly for all subdirectories?