# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'modules'

Tags: python, class

This is related to a SO question, the solution to which gives me the error noted.

[How can I get a list of all classes within current module in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1796180/python-get-list-of-all-classes-within-current-module)

Using the green-checked code from that SO answer, I want to get a list of all class names in my own module, locations.py:

```
import locations

def print_classes():
    for name, obj in inspect.getmembers(locations.modules[__name__]):
        if inspect.isclass(obj):
            print obj

print_classes()
```

When I run this, I get AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'modules'

I have tested locations.py -- it contains 31 skeleton classes; it throws no errors.

Comment: you're not using the green checked code.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath - I thought I was adapting it to suit my module.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The accepted answer uses [`sys.modules`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.modules), **not** `locations.modules`:

```
for name, obj in inspect.getmembers(sys.modules[__name__]):
```

`sys.modules` is the Python dictionary holding all imported module objects:

> This is a dictionary that maps module names to modules which have already been loaded. This can be manipulated to force reloading of modules and other tricks. Note that removing a module from this dictionary is not the same as calling `reload()` on the corresponding module object.

In your case, you don't need `sys.modules`, you already *have* a reference to the module object. You just imported it, so just use it directly:

```
for name, obj in inspect.getmembers(locations):
```

Comment: does sys.modules give class name ?

Comment: @yopy: `sys.modules` is a dictionary. It has keys and values, keys being the module name, the values being the module objects. Module objects have attributes; these are the objects defined in that module. If one of those attributes is a class, then **that class** will have a name.

Comment: Thank you -- this does what I want:

`def print_classes():
    for name, obj in inspect.getmembers(locations):
        if inspect.isclass(obj):
            print name`

Answer (score 0):

You can fix that by changing to `sys.modules['locations']` or `locations`:

**NB: if you are testing from the same module itself, than you can use : `sys.modules[__name__]`**

```
>>> import locations
>>> sys.modules['locations']
<module 'locations' from 'locations.pyc'>
>>> locations
<module 'locations' from 'locations.pyc'>
>>>
```

**Here is my locations.py module**

```
class A(object): pass
class B(object): pass
class C(object): pass
class D(object): pass
```

**And here is my testing.py script:**

```
import locations
import inspect

def print_classes():
    for name, obj in inspect.getmembers(locations):
        if inspect.isclass(obj):
            print obj

print_classes()
```

Output:

```
<class 'locations.A'>
<class 'locations.B'>
<class 'locations.C'>
<class 'locations.D'>
```

Comment: This is not the code that raised the error for the OP, which is *why* the question was posted in the first place.

Comment: ya i changed `locations.modules[__name__]` to locations

Comment: Exactly, so you might want to explain what the difference is, why you changed that.

Answer (score 0):

You might prefer a list comprehension, since the loop is quite small.

```
from __future__ import print_function
from inspect import getmembers, isclass
import my_module

[print(obj) for obj in getmembers(my_module) if isclass(obj)]
```