# Finding python code snippets with regex

Tags: python, regex

I have a python file, which looks something like this:

```
class Hello():
    something = 0
    someotherthing = 2

class Heythere():
    whatsthis()
    def whatsthis():
        dosomething=0

class Anotherclass():
    imavar=2
    whatsup='?'

....
```

And it continues like this for some time, there are a lot of classes. I want to capture each class into a list using a regular expression. I always want the regex to start capturing the strings at "class" and always want it to stop where there are two line breaks in a row. Here is what I tried, and got nowhere. I am not familiar with regular expression syntax at all so maybe I am doing things completely wrong:

```
import re

r = open('python.py','r').read()
x = re.findall(r'(class?)\n\n', r)
```

x always returns an empty list []

Not sure where I am doing this wrong, but I am fairly certain my syntax is completely off. I just... don't know where to start

Comment: why don't you start with `open(...).read().split('\n\n')`  then the regex will be much easier :-)

Comment: I would *strongly* suggest not parsing the code with regex.  If you need a list of classes in a module look into the `inspect` module.  Also, this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1796180/python-get-list-of-all-classes-within-current-module.

Comment: Well both of those answers are way better than what I was thinking :) Thanks guys!

Comment: Also, the `ast` module can parse Python code without running it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this regex will capture your groups

```
((?:.*\n){1,5}.*)\n\n
```

demo here : http://rubular.com/r/MBLLb2m8WG

Answer (score 0):

is this anything like what you want?

```
import re
r = open('python.py','r').read()
x = re.findall(r'class .+', r)
```

Comment: A context manager would be appropriate here. `with open('python.py','r') as fin: r = fin.read()`