# Is it possible to get a list of imported things from a module in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Is it possible to get the list of imported classes from a module?

My code is something like this:

```
from .models import Food, Drink, Topping

for m in (Food, Drink, Topping):
    admin.site.register(m)
```

where I always have to repeat the imported elements.

Is it possible to do something like:

```
from .models import Food, Drink, Topping

for m in list_of_things_imported_from[".models"]:
    admin.site.register(m)
```

I tried looking up on google and SO without good results.

Comment: I hope this link my help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1796180/how-can-i-get-a-list-of-all-classes-within-current-module-in-python

Comment: a comment before was suggesting dir(), but dir() first of all returns an array of strings, then I would have the overhead of getting the class from a string, and second it returns more things, not only the things imported from .models.

Answer (score 3):

```
import inspect
import test_module # module to be inspected

for name, data in inspect.getmembers(test_module):
    if name.startswith("__"):
        continue
    if 'class' in str(data):
        print(name)
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution I just thought could be to make my own function that imports from .models and registers the elements, like

```
def import_and_register(arg_list):
    for a in arg_list:
        from .models import a
        admin.site.register(a)
```

But can I do this with a builtin feature? Are there any major cons to this approach?

Comment: One potential downside is the cognitive overhead for future programmers. It's a simple function, so I wouldn't call it a "major con" but if "everyone" does it the way you demonstrate in your original question, perhaps it's best to leave it alone.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is, but perhaps to save yourself from <del>typing</del> remember the names, just store them in a collection.

```
from .models import Food, Drink, Topping

MY_FANCY_MODELS = Food, Drink, Topping

for m in MY_FANCY_MODELS:
    admin.site.register(m)
```

Comment: this is more typing than my current approach :)

Comment: I'm sorry @ninazzo I assumed you wanted to type that over and over again. I also used a purposely long variable name.

Answer (score 0):

I feel, you can do it like this -

```
import models
for i in dir(models):
    if isinstance(i, type):
        admin.site.register(i)
```

dir(models) retrieves all the attributes of module.

Comment: But what if in models there's something I do not want to register?

Comment: Yes that's the downside of this approach. I suggested this approach based on the requirement  `list_of_things_imported_from[".models"]` you asked in the question.