# How to get classes declared in the top level python file

Tags: python, reflection

Is there a simple way to retrieve all the classes declared in the top-level python file?

For example :

```
import inspect                                                                                                          
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
class FirstClass:                                                                                                       
    pass                                                                                                                
                                                                                                                         
class SecondClass:                                                                                                      
    pass                                                                                                                
                                                                                                                        
if __name__ == '__main__':                                                                                              
    print(inspect.getmembers(__name__))
```

I was trying to print FirstClass and SecondClass.

I've tried with inspect module without a success as shown before

I've tried with dir() however it stops working when it is called inside a function.

```
print(dir())
```

will result:
['FirstClass', 'SecondClass', '**annotations**', '**builtins**', '**cached**', '**doc**', '**file**', '**loader**', '**name**', '**package**', '**spec**', 'inspect']

The list contains the classes I'am looking for.However when it is called inside another scope  like function the result is different.

```
def getdir():
   print(dir())
```

it will print an empty list

I've looked at the post however it does not solve the problem when the `__name__` is equal `'__main__'`

*How can I get a list of all classes within current module in Python?*([How can I get a list of all classes within current module in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1796180/how-can-i-get-a-list-of-all-classes-within-current-module-in-python))

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I get a list of all classes within current module in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1796180/how-can-i-get-a-list-of-all-classes-within-current-module-in-python)

Comment: the problem raises when ```__name__ == '__main__'```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `globals()` to access your module globals, and inspect to filter for classes only:

```py
import inspect


class FirstClass:
    pass


class SecondClass:
    pass


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print([obj for obj in globals().values() if inspect.isclass(obj)])
```

But beware, `import` imports in globals, so if for example you add `from gzip import GzipFile` you'll get it in the list.